# Integer to ipv4 with winsock.h

Tags: c, windows, ipv4

I have a question concerning the use of union library winsock.h to convert the numbers to ipv4 address how to write?

```
#ifdef obsolete
        union {
                struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
                struct { u_short s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
                u_long S_addr;
        } S_un;
```

Comment: You need to elaborate, what is your question exactly?

Comment: The `#ifdef obsolete` sounds a little ominous.

Comment: well, I have a lib http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/include/winsock.h.htm and a must convert integer to ipv4 adress (4byte). eg IN:
2655715960

OUT:
158:75:2:120
9E:4B:2:78

Comment: this is no IPv4 address: it contains colons (`:`)!?

Comment: just instead of '.' I use the ':'

Comment: lukassz: ok, this is making no sense at all.. IPv4 addresses contain dots, IPv6 addresses contain colons, and you seem to mix them all up...

Comment: Take a look at http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sockaddr_inman.html, it contains examples of what you (seem to) want.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
S_un addr;

addr.S_addr = htonl( 2655715960 );

printf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu  %hhX:%hhX:%hhX:%hhX \n",
       addr.S_un_b.s_b1, addr.S_un_b.s_b2, addr.S_un_b.s_b3, addr.S_un_b.s_b4,
       addr.S_un_b.s_b1, addr.S_un_b.s_b2, addr.S_un_b.s_b3, addr.S_un_b.s_b4 );
```

The magic number `2655715960` is the example input value from your comment.
The code will print the wanted line:

```
158.75.2.120  9E:4B:2:78
```

Note:  It is not common to print IPv4 addresses by using hex.

Note2: Use `struct in_addr` instead of `S_un`. So you can use `inet_ntoa` function for converting IP number to string.

Answer (score 0):

Using my magic glass sphere, I'm trying to guess what's asked here:

[sockaddr_storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could take IPv4 as well as IPv6 addresses.

`ss_family` indicates what's stored inside.

Depending on it's setting, it's either a `sockaddr_in` (for IPv4) or `sockaddr_in6` (for IPv6) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx).